# Issue with Wordpress After Moving Files

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So I moved my installation of WP to a different folder in my web directory (to the root from a sub directory /wp) and now I have a fatal error, and cannot seem to fix it. Here are the errors:

```
Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in D:\Hosting\2974365\html\wp-includes\class-wp-roles.php on line 126


Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\Hosting\2974365\html\wp-includes\class-wp-roles.php on line 126

Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets in D:\Hosting\2974365\html\wp-includes\widgets.php on line 1141
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated... can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: @HappyCoding do you want him to post the code for wordpress?

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the database, not the actual php code because I reinstalled fresh, but it still gave me errors.

Comment: @flauntster i thought he put some custom code in function file

Comment: This seems to be the same issue you're facing: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/site-address-change-from-subdirectory-to-root-site-now-not-accessable/

Comment: I've read that, didn't get any help from it. I tired what the mod said. @TimSheehan

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you move Wordpress, you need to change the siteurl and the home to the new path. Apart from that, if you have posts, you also need to update their URL. Here is some SQL to help you do it, make sure you change the OLD_URL and NEW_URL fields.

Login phpMyAdmin, select the database and after you change the fields, execute the following queries:

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'OLD_URL', 'NEW_URL') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'OLD_URL','NEW_URL');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'OLD_URL', 'NEW_URL');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'OLD_URL', 'NEW_URL');

Comment: This can be related with magic_quotes_runtime being turned on in your config. You might try to override it with ini_set() if your host turned this on.
Try to set magic_quotes_gpc and magic_quotes_runtime to ‘0’.

Someone else had similar problem, check here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-unset-string-offsets-on-brand-new-installation/#post-690693

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the 'siteurl' option in the wp_options table.